# Как сделать, чтобы пользователь должен был удерживать палец на экране и перемещать вверх, вниз?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Много где читал, но везде или свайп, или просто нажатие на экран. Как сделать, чтобы пользователь должен был удерживать палец на экране и перемещать им вверх и вниз, соответственно меняя направление объекта вверх или вниз. После того, как отпустил, объект просто остаётся в том положении как его оставили.

В игре двигается 2D объект: пуля. Физика на ней не задействована, двигается с помощью координат. Пуля просто постоянно движется влево.

Желательно ответить кодом, пожалуйста

Сам код игры очень простой:

```
   public class BulletControl : MonoBehaviour
   {

       Vector3 moveVec;

       public float speed = 5;

       // Update is called once per frame
       void FixedUpdate()
       {
           transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
       }
   }
```

P.S. на ошибки можете не обращать внимания, их больше нет, они - результат неудачного опыта
[image: Игра]

Comment: У вас ошибка - Код перемещения самой пули в вашем случае надо описать не в FixedUpdate, а в Update

Comment: Вот, к примеру, отличный туториал по вашему запросу. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVxnvXonGXY

Comment: Большое спасибо